# Dynamically scheduling events in AWS EventBridge from a Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have the following two equivalent lambda functions:

setNotification(date, text):

```
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
const params = {
    Entries: [
      {
        Source: "com.aws.message-event-lambda",
        EventBusName: "",
        DetailType: "message",
        Detail: JSON.stringify({
          title: event.detail.title,
          text: event.detail.text,
        }),
      },
    ],
  };
  await eventbridge.putEvents(params).promise();
};
```

sendNotification(text)

Currently I am using Event bridge to trigget th sendNotification function from the setNotification function, but it triggers the function immediatley.

How can I trigger the sendNotification function at a sppecific date defined by the setNotification function?

Currently I see the following 2 options:

1. Create code inside the setNotification function that creates a scheduled rule on the EventBridge
2. Stop using EventBridge and use step functions.

I would like to know what is the correct approach between these two or if there is a better approach which i havent found.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the setNotification(date, text) lambda?

Comment: Yes kind sir here you go although it is more of an architectural question.
sentNotification:

`exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => { 

    const params = {

        Entries:[
    {
      // Event envelope fields
      Source: "com.aws.message-event-lambda",
      EventBusName: "",
      DetailType: "message",
      Detail: JSON.stringify({
        "title": event.detail.title,
        "text": event.detail.text
      })
    }]
      
    } 
    await eventbridge.putEvents(params).promise();
}`

Comment: I tried to format that comment as best I could but clearly im new to commenting here, apologies.

Comment: It's better if you update your question to include it. I want to check the setNotification lambda, because I don't see why you need it. You can directly point the EventBridge to the sentNotification lambda and skip setNotification.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question, the function is meant to be called by a front end event scheduling app, so lets say someone wants to set up a birthday reminder, then they would use the app which calls the setNotification function.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you need a different architecture including a lambda function called by a cron expression on the eventbridge that checks a DB for entries to then send notifications to.

More information on scheduling systems on AWS in the following link:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/serverless-scheduling-with-amazon-eventbridge-aws-lambda-and-amazon-dynamodb/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).